# NSString to NSDate convert

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string that contain date:

```
2012-05-25
```

and i wan to convert this string to NSDate:

```
NSString *birthday = /*2012-05-25*/;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];


NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:birthday];
```

and in the dateFromString i get the date of today.

Comment: try using `yyyy-MM-dd` as format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works :

```
NSString *birthday = @"2012-05-25";     
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];        
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:birthday];
NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
```

Outputs :

> 2012-01-25 11:36:38.157 dsv[2679:903] 2012-05-25 00:00:00 +0200

Please refer to the [Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) for details.

Comment: i try it but i get one day before the date i entered: '2012-05-24 21:00:00 +0000'

Comment: please read the full doc at the link I provided. I don't know the details, but it may be related to the locale. There are also plenty of questions here about this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps u. try this

```
 - (NSDate*) dateFromString:(NSString*)aStr
    {

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

        NSLog(@"%@", aStr);
        NSDate   *aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:aStr];
        [dateFormatter release];
        return aDate;
    }
```